# Form Button open a new page onclick

Tags: javascript, button, onclick

I'm calling the script below on a button onclick, where .value is a URL dependent on a drop down section. I want the resulting URL to open in a new window ('_blank') when the button is clicked. How can I modify this code to do that? Any help is appreciated.

```
function openResultsPage() {
    if(document.getElementById('selectedRace').value){
                            window.location.href = document.getElementById('selectedRace').value;
                        }   
                    }
```

Comment: New windows can be opened via `window.open(uri, window_name [, settings]);` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.open

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
function openResultsPage() {
  if(document.getElementById('selectedRace').value){
    var href = document.getElementById('selectedRace').value
    window.open(href,'_blank').value;
  }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use window.open to open a new window

**NOTE:** I am using height and width in third parameter to make sure that window.open open new window instead of new tab

```
function openResultsPage() {
    if(document.getElementById('selectedRace').value) {
        window.open(document.getElementById('selectedRace').value,'','width=700, height=500');
    }  
}
```

Comment: Im sorry for the confusion. A new tab is what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
<head>
<base target="_blank">
</head>
```